# How to chain promises within nested for loops?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, promise

```
var verifyEmail = function (thisEmail){
    return new Promise(
        function (resolve, reject) {
            quickemailverification.verify(thisEmail, function (err, response) {
              // Print response object
              console.log(response.body);
              if (response.body["success"] == "true"){
                  var validity = response.body["result"];
                  if (validity == "valid"){
                    console.log("Email Valid!");
                    resolve(validity);
                  } else {
                    console.log("Email Invalid!")
                    resolve(validity);
                  }
              } else {
                  var reason = new Error("API unsuccessful");
                  reject(reason);
              }
            });
        }
    );
};

var saveValidity = function (validity){
    return new Promise(
        function (resolve, reject){
            if (validity == "valid"){
                var state = true;
                admin.database().ref("/users_unverified/"+keys[i]+"/emails/"+x+"/verified/").set(state, function(error) {
                  if (error) {
                    console.log("Email ("+thisEmail+") verfication could not be saved" + error);
                  }
                  console.log("Email verification saved: " +thisEmail);
                });
            } else {
                state = false;
                admin.database().ref("/users_unverified/"+keys[i]+"/emails/"+x+"/verified/").set(state, function(error) {
                  if (error) {
                    console.log("Email ("+thisEmail+") verfication could not be saved" + error);
                  }
                  console.log("Email verification saved: " +thisEmail);
                });
            }
        }
    );
};

admin.database().ref("/users_unverified/").once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    var snap = snapshot.val();
    keys = Object.keys(snap);

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        var emails = snap[keys[i]]["emails"];
        if (emails){
            for (var x = 0; x<emails.length; x++){
                var thisEmail = emails[x]["email"];
                var emailVerified = emails[x]["verified"];
                if (emailVerified != true || emailVerified != false){
                    verifyEmail
                        .then(saveValidity)
                        .then(function (fulfilled) {
                            console.log(fulfilled);
                        })
                        .catch(function (error){
                            console.log(error.message);
                        });
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Above is the code I put together. I'm not all too convinced that it will work. I'm new to promises, so I'm trying to understand how to do this right.

The verifyEmail function should take in the email address from the firebase query in the third chunk of the code. The saveValidity function should take on the validity response from verifyEmail.

But, what I'm also worried about the nested for loop I have in the firebase query block. I'm looping through each user to validate their emails, but each user sometimes also has multiple emails. I'm worried that it will loop on to the next user before finishing checking all the emails of the previous user.

I'm also not sure if I can pass data into the promise functions the way I did.

Could definitely use some help here. Really trying hard to understand how this works.

Comment: Include parentheses to call `verifyEmail` in the for loop , as in `verifyEmail()   .then(.....)`

Comment: Oh. Yes, definitely! Then the rest looks good?! :o

Comment: Do you really, really want to wait for each user, in turn? I mean, you probably don't want to do quite what you're doing, because it's hard to figure out when you're finished... but the answer I would give would be different if you said: "No, you can validate 10 users at the same time, but the 'user' isn't valid until every one of their emails checks out", versus "yes, I need to make sure that every single email from every single user is done, before I start on a new user". What do you want to do, when: An email is valid/invalid; A user is valid/invalid; A list of users is valid/invalid

Comment: @ryangineer you also need to call the `resolve` or `reject` function of the promise returned by `saveValidity`. You may want to reject if the validity can't  be saved as well. And why check the snapshot counter `i` against `100` instead of `keys.length`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to fix `saveValidity()` to always resolve or reject the promise and to pass in the other variables `key` and `thisEmail` that it references:

```
const saveValidity = function (validity, key, thisEmail){
    return new Promise(
        function (resolve, reject){
            if (validity == "valid"){
                let state = true;
                admin.database().ref("/users_unverified/"+key+"/emails/"+x+"/verified/").set(state, function(error) {
                  if (error) {
                    let msg = "Email ("+thisEmail+") verfication could not be saved" + error;
                    console.log(msg);
                    reject(new Error("Email ("+thisEmail+") verfication could not be saved" + error));
                  } else {
                    resolve("Email verification saved: " +thisEmail);
                  }
                });
            } else {
                state = false;
                admin.database().ref("/users_unverified/"+keys[i]+"/emails/"+x+"/verified/").set(state, function(error) {
                  if (error) {
                    let msg = "Email ("+thisEmail+") verfication could not be saved" + error;
                    console.log(msg);
                    reject(new Error(msg));
                  } else {
                    resolve("Email verification saved: " +thisEmail);
                  }
                });
            }
        }
    );
};
```

Then, several changes are made to your main loop:

1. I assume we can run all the `verifyEmail()` calls in parallel since they don't appear to have anything to do with one another.
2. Change `verifyEmail.then(...)` to verifyEmail(thisEmail).then(...)` to actually call the function
3. Collect all the `verifyEmail()` promises in an array
4. Call `Promise.all()` on the array of promises to monitor when they are all done
5. Return value from `.then()` so we get the returned values in `Promise.all()`
6. rethrow in `.catch()` so promise stays rejected and will filter back to `Promise.all()`.  You could eat errors here if you want to ignore them and continue with others.
7. Switch from `var` to `let`
8. Change from `!=` to `!==` since it looks like your  explicitly looking for a `true` or `false` value and don't want type casting.
9. Pass in the variables that `saveValidity()` needs.
10. Change logic when comparing `emailVerified` because what you had before was always true and thus probably not the right logic.  I think what you want is to know when `emailVerified` is not yet set to `true` or to `false` which means you have to use `&&`, not `||`.
11. Compare outer `for` loop with `keys.length`, not hard-coded value of `100`.

And, here's the resulting code for the main nested `for` loop:

```
admin.database().ref("/users_unverified/").once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    let snap = snapshot.val();
    let keys = Object.keys(snap);

    let promises = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        let key = keys[i];
        let emails = snap[key]["emails"];
        if (emails){
            for (let x = 0; x < emails.length; x++) {
                let currentKey = key;
                let thisEmail = emails[x]["email"];
                let emailVerified = emails[x]["verified"];
                if (emailVerified !== true && emailVerified !== false){
                    promises.push(verifyEmail(thisEmail).then(validity => {
                        return saveValidity(validity, currentKey, thisEmail);
                    }).then(function (fulfilled) {
                        console.log(fulfilled);
                        return fulfilled;      // after logging return value so it stays the resolved value
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error.message);
                        throw error;           // rethrow so promise stays rejected
                    }));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}).then(results => {
    // all results done here
}).catch(err => {
    // error here
});
```

Comment: @jfriend100, okay first of all.... WOW. I'm going to be studying this over and over again. Thank you so much.

One fear I had, though, was that the outer For Loop would move on (i++) before the inner For Loop completes. What part of your changes prevents this from happening?

Thanks so much. As I said, going to be studying this for a while!

Comment: @ryangineer - The outer `for` loop does move on before things are done in the inner loop.  The only place I saw that that might be a problem was the need for the `currentKey` in `saveValidity()` so I put that in a `let` variable in the loop which gives each run through the `for` loop its own separate copy of the variable.  This purposely runs all your verify operations in parallel (which should be faster) because the code you showed offer no reason why they couldn't be run in parallel.  It would be a bit of a different design to run them all in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If ES2017 is available in your case, you can just use the keywords `await` and `async` to do that directly. Following is an example:

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) { 
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(x);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function f1() {
  var x = await resolveAfter2Seconds(10);
  console.log(x); // 10
}
f1();
```

And you can read more about async/await [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

If you want to do that without async/await to achieve better browser compatibility, you can use [Babel](https://babeljs.io) to do the pre-compile.

If you really want a lightwight implementation, you can use a function named `chainPromiseThunks`, or `chain` for short. This `chain` function accepts an Array of Thunks of Promises, And returns a new Thunk of Promise, Following is an one-line-implementation of `chain`:

```
const chain = thunks => thunks.reduce((r, a) => () => r().then(a));
```

And here is a usage demo:

```
const echo = x =>
    new Promise(function(resolve) {
        return setTimeout((function() {
            console.log(x);
            return resolve(x);
        }), 1000);
    })
;

const pThunks = [1,2,3,4,5].map(i => () => echo(i));

chain(pThunks)();
```